Insertar múltiples registros con procedimientos almacenados en SQL Server desde Python
Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server:
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insertar_EstadisticasApoyo]
(
    @codigo INT
    ,@anio_mes varchar(6)
    ,@categoria varchar(2)
    ,@subcategoria varchar(2)
    ,@total_facturado decimal(13, 4)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EstadisticasApoyo (codigo_producto, anio_mes, cate, suca, total)
    VALUES (@codigo, @anio_mes, @categoria, @subcategoria, @total_facturado);
END

Por otra parte, tengo un archivo en Python que me recorre un archivo .csv y me inserta unas columnas en la BD SQL Server a través del procedimiento almacenado (solo copiaré lo relacionado con la inserción y la interacción con la BD).
def connect_to_sql_server():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
        'SERVER=DESARROLLO;'
        'DATABASE=ESTADISTICAS;'
        'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )
    conn.autocommit = True
    return conn

# Función para ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado y guardar los datos
def execute_stored_procedure(conn, data):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    inserted_count = 0

    for _, row in data.iterrows():
        try:
            intTipoServicio = int(row['TipoServicio']) # Convertir a INT
            strAnoMesFactura = str(int(row['AnoMesFactura'])).strip() # Convertir a VARCHAR
            strCategoria = str(int(row['Categoria'])).strip() # Convertir a VARCHAR
            strSubCategoria = str(int(row['SubCategoria'])).strip() # Convertir a VARCHAR
            fltValorTotalFacturado = float(row['ValorTotalFacturado']) # Convertir a DECIMAL(13,4)
            cursor.execute("""
                EXEC Insertar_EstadisticasApoyo ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
                """,
                intTipoServicio,
                strAnoMesFactura,
                strCategoria,
                strSubCategoria,
                fltValorTotalFacturado
            )
            inserted_count += 1
        except Exception as e:
            ##print(f"Error al insertar el registro: {e}")
            print(f"Error al insertar el registro: {e} -- Tipo de servicio: T{intTipoServicio}T  -- Añomesfactura: A{strAnoMesFactura}A -- SCategory: C{strCategoria}C -- Subcateg: S{strSubCategoria}S -- ValorFacturado: V{fltValorTotalFacturado}V")

    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    return inserted_count

Todo funciona correctamente e inserta adecuadamente... Pero cuando tengo muuuuchos registros (1 millón por ejemplo) se vuelve lento (claro, porque inserta uno por uno).
¿Cómo insertar en bloque muchos registros desde Python con un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server?
NOTA: Solo puedo hacer inserciones con procedimientos almacenados, no puedo usar directamente el INSERT desde Python ya que la aplicación no tendrá permisos de inserción cuando esté en productivo.

Realmente la manera más eficiente de insertar datos en SQL Server es utilizar su interfaz Bulk Copy. Esta interfaz está disponible de múltiples maneras y para distintos entornos y lenguajes. Por ejemplo tenemos la herramienta de línea de comando bcp o el comando SQL BULK INSERT.
Desde lenguajes de programación como c# tenemos la clase SqlBulkCopy, en otros lenguajes también están disponibles. Y Python no iba a ser menos.
Pero si como dices tienes una limitación de permisos que hace que la aplicación no pueda insertar directamente en la tabla sino que tiene que ser por medio de procedimientos almacenados, pues realmente es un inconveniente, puesto que no podrás obtener el espetacular rendimiento que te proporciona la interfaz Bulk Copy.
Sin embargo no está todo perdido, podrás aumentar mucho el rendimiento de la inserción masiva. La técnica que te propongo consiste en crear y usar un procedimiento almacenado que tenga como parámetro un XML o un JSON que contenga cientos o miles de registros y los inserte de un plumazo.
Voy a poner un ejemplo usando JSON para la tabla:
CREATE TABLE my_simple_table
(
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    some_text varchar(50)
)

Este sería el procedimiento almacenado:
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_into_my_simle_table
    @json nvarchar(max)
AS
    INSERT INTO my_simple_table(id, some_text)
    SELECT id, some_text
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH (
        id int,
        some_text varchar(50)
    )
GO

Y para ejecutarlo simplemente le tienes que pasar el JSON esperado. Por ejemplo:
EXEC insert_into_my_simle_table N'
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "some_text": "whatever 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "some_text": "whatever 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "some_text": "whatever 3"
    }
]'

Desde Python le pasas un parametro de tipo nvarchar(max) con el JSON.
Puedes probar con lotes de cientos o incluso miles de registros. Verás como el rendimiento mejora considerablemente.
